# how to echo html img tag from a array in a foreach loop in php

Tags: php, html, arrays, loops, foreach

Am tying to display the img from the array, which is in a foreach loop but i can't echo out the img from the array in the php code to display it in html. Please help.

```
<?php
$products[107] = array(
    "name" => "Logo Shirt, Turquoise",
    "img" => "img/shirts/shirt-107.jpg",    
    "describtion" => "7 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae."
);
$products[108] = array(
    "name" => "Logo Shirt, Orange",
    "img" => "img/shirts/shirt-108.jpg",    
    "describtion" => "8 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.",
);
$products[109] = array(
    "name" => "Logo Shirt, Orange",
    "img" => "img/shirts/shirt-108.jpg",    
    "describtion" => "9 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.",
);

?>       
        <section  class="generic gallery">
          <div class="container" >
      <?php foreach ($products as $product) { 
          echo '<div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item" >';
          echo '<a href="#">';
      --> echo '<img src="' . $products . '" alt="Screen shot" /></p>';
          ?><h3> <?php echo $product["name"];?> </h3>
          <p><?php echo $product["describtion"];?></p>
          <?php 
          echo '</a>';
          echo '</br>';
          echo '</div>'; 
        }
      ?>
      </div>
    </section>
    <br>
```

Comment: just echo it with the index included just like the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with -

```
echo '<p><img src="' . $product['img'] . '" alt="Screen shot" height="200" width="200" /></p>';
```

Comment: thanks the pictures show but they are not the same size, how can i Display them all with the same size using the your code.

Comment: Updated the answer. Or you can use css for styling them.

Comment: Happy to help you..And please accept the answer if it solved the problem.